# Create a new column from string match without NA

Tags: r

Using this

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("<h1> Title </h1> keep me here <h1>not </h1> or <h2> else</h2>","also not here <h1> but</h1> here also"))
stringr::str_match(df1$text, 'Title </h1>\\s(.*)\\s<h1>')[, 2]
```

It provides a row which results

```
"keep me here" NA
```

How can someone make the result as a new column where for every row which has anything receive 0 instead of NA?

Expected result:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("keep me here",0))
```

Comment: use `stringr::str_match(df1$text, 'Title </h1>\\s(.*)\\s<h1>')[,2][1]`

Comment: @AlexB thank you. I tried but this option provides only the complete case and not a new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have pointed out before, instead of trying to parse html with regex, it is far better to use a dedicated html parser to navigate the html fragments you have. It is worth learning this technique to avoid having to constantly rewrite complex regex expressions.

Please have a look at xpath expressions on a resource such as w3schools where you can learn to easily select any node according to its tag name or attributes, or relationship to other nodes.

For example, in this case you wish to select the text node that follows any `h1 tag` containing the text `Title`. Without using regex at all, you can do this with the xpath expression `//h1[contains(text(), 'Title')]/following-sibling::text()`

For example:

```r
library(rvest)

my_xpath <- "//h1[contains(text(), 'Title')]/following-sibling::text()"

df1$text <- sapply(df1$text, function(fragment) {
  result <- read_html(paste0("<html>", fragment, "</html>")) %>%
  html_node(xpath = my_xpath) %>%
  html_text()
  if(is.na(result)) 0 else trimws(result)
}, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

df1
#>   id         text
#> 1  1 keep me here
#> 2  2            0
```

I think all of the questions that you have posted in the last couple of weeks could be solved in exactly the same way by simply modifying the xpath expression above

Comment: Thank you. Right and quick option. I have one problem, I have some columns where there is not html tag. In this lines there error. What can I do?

Comment: @foc just make sure that the string is recognised as html by pasting a "html" tag around it. See my update

Comment: thank you here an example with the problem `df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c("<h1> Title </h1> keep me here <h1>not </h1> or <h2> else</h2>","also not here <h1> but</h1> here also", "just a simple text here"))`

Comment: @foc with my updated code, this gives the correct output for `df1$text` - returning `c("keep me here", "0", "0")`

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that uses `grepl` to yield boolean pattern matches, converts `FALSE` matches to zero and `gsub` the `(.*)` group using `gsub`,

```
mFUN <- function(x, s="<h1> Title </h1> (.*) <h1>not </h1> or <h2> else</h2>") {
  g <- grepl(s, x)
  x[!g] <- 0
  x[g] <- gsub(s, "\\1", x[g])
  x
}

with(df1, data.frame(id, text=mFUN(text)))
#   id         text
# 1  1 keep me here
# 2  2            0
```